# Does anyone know how to get a list of all the Qiskit ML datasets, and if they can also be used for classical machine learning?

Tags: qiskit, machine-learning

I am trying to create a Quantum Classifier and would like to try to test it out using a Qiskit ML dataset. However, I only know of the breast cancer dataset and I would like to try it on another dataset.

On another note, I am also curious if the Qiskit ML datasets are usable for classical machine learning, for example, using TensorFlow.

Answer (score 1):

Qiskit uses the datasets provided by `sklearn` and all the ones built into Qiskit are available [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/tree/master/qiskit/ml/datasets). You could follow how these methods work to load your own dataset if you wanted to.

You should be able to use the return from the call to the dataset directly for classical machine learning methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Tensorflow to perform this.
Below are few mentioned:
[A cross-platform Python library for quantum machine learning, automatic differentiation, and optimization of hybrid quantum-classical computations](https://pennylane.ai/)
[Introduction of the first dedicated machine learning platform for quantum computers](https://www.xanadu.ai/software/)

[It's Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/StrawberryFields/)